# .jar UI not working in Linux redhat/centos 7.X

Tags: java, linux

I have a JAR file which is used to convert txt file to PDF. I am not sure on which platform it was build.
While running this jar in linux, the UI is not visible.
Jar is working properly in windows
There are 2 files, jar and bat file; bat file is a trigger.

You can download the file here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bnNVMdYwCLUeYSB7RH1oi29ygvmH9HCa

and please post your suggestions.

What I have tried,

This utility requires, java 1.6+; I have tried java 1.7 and 1.8 --- did not work

Changed java classpath to “.:jarfile:bin_path” --- did not work

Tried –verbose option, no failed component found

$JAVA_HOME AND $CLASSPATH ARE FINE

Tried:  java –Xmx1024m –jar jarfile.jar –did not work

One batch file is attached with utility, which is to trigger jar file; it contains javaw command which is not available in linux. So I am using java – jar command.

bat file contains :

```
@echo off

set CHK_JAVA=""

set TEMP_FILE=%TEMP%\javaCheck%RANDOM%%TIME:~9,5%.txt


if %TEMP_FILE%=="" (
    set TEMP_FILE=C:\javaCheck%RANDOM%%TIME:~9,5%.txt
)

echo TRACES PDF Generation Utility to generate Form 16 / 16A requires JAVA Version 1.6 or above.

java -version 2>%TEMP_FILE%

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%TEMP_FILE%) do (
  echo %%i | find "version" >nul
  if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo %%i | find "1.6" >nul
    if not errorlevel 1 (
      set CHK_JAVA="OK"
    )
    echo %%i | find "1.7" >nul
        if not errorlevel 1 (
          set CHK_JAVA="OK"
    )
    echo %%i | find "1.8" >nul
        if not errorlevel 1 (
          set CHK_JAVA="OK"
     )
  )
)

del %TEMP_FILE%

if %CHK_JAVA%=="OK" (
  echo Launching now
  rem echo %~dp0TRACES-PDF-CONVERTER.jar
  rem pause
  start javaw -Xms1024m -jar %~dp0TRACES-PDF-CONVERTERV1.3L.jar
) else (

  echo You do not have JRE version 1.6 or above required to launch TRACES PDF Generation Utility.
  echo Please install JRE version 1.6 or above and try again.
  echo Visit http://www.java.com/en/download/index.jsp for JRE download details.
  pause
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to run a .bat file on Linux? You cannot, .bat files are only for Windows. No way to run them on Linux. You have to create a shell file for Linux.

Comment: Nope, i am not trying to run bat file, i just want to run jar file in linux.